# HTML5 video size vs poster size is wrong in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video, video-encoding

I used Miro Video Converter (http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) to convert a .mov to different html5 video formats (webm, ogv and mp4). I manually made a poster image from the 1st frame of the video.

Everything works fine in Firefox and Safari, but when using Chrome, the video seems to be a little bigger than it should be. It's easy to notice when looking at the difference between the poster image and the beginning of the video.

I am wondering if someone has ever encountered the same problem and if the problem here is either my video file or the embedding.

Here is a jsfiddle with the actual files : http://jsfiddle.net/aLvpP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so, if anyone ever comes here, I finally found the answer to this.

The reason why Chrome was showing a bigger/blurry video is that the mp4 version of it was not in a standard 16:9 format, but not too far from it, so it was kind of stretching it a bit.

Actually, part of the blame is on Miro Video Converter, because when I tried using FFmpeg to convert my original mov to the mp4 format, FFmpeg would not let me do it, explicitly telling me that "the width of the video can not be divided by 16".

All in all, changing the format of the original video to a standard 16:9 format solved the problem.